# AngularJs: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs

I created the modules and booted the app the `document`, I got the below errors. I can't figure out what is the problem with my module. Maybe I use the wrong way for module creation in angular.

Output

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.directives due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.factories due to:
Error: [$in...<omitted>...1)
```

Modules

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'app.templates',
  'app.directives',
  'app.services',
  'app.factories',
]);

angular.module('app.templates', []);
angular.module('app.services', []);

angular.module('app.directives', [
  'app.templates',
  'app.factories'
]);

angular.module('app.factories', [
  'toaster',               
  'ngStorage',
  'app.services'
 ]);


angular.module('app.factories')
   .factory('NotificationSvc',function($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, toaster){
     ...
});


$(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document ,['app']);
});
```

Comment: Do you have the `Error: [$in...<omitted>...1)` full part?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, `Error: [$in...<omitted>...1)` is something like this [$injector:modulerr], it is just short form.

Comment: Of all the dependencies, toaster and ngStorage are not native of angular. they are third party services for angular. Are you sure you included those js files?

Comment: I used `gulp-concat-vendor` to concatenate all vendors to `vendor.js` that are installed by bower, I'm sure that I included.

Comment: There is no error if `toaster` and `ngStorage` are removed. So if you include them make sure you've included all dependencies to use them. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7MwqL/

Comment: You are right, I have problem with toaster. Thanks